# how to get the max row in a sql table? see sample table below

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got sql table below:

```
ID   Value
10    5
10    6
11    6 
12    7
13   10
13   11
```

**How to return it in sql query where only the max value per ID (if the ID got more than two rows)?*

```
ID |  Value
10    6
11    6 
12    7
13   11
```

Answer (score 3):

Group by the column you want to be unique. Aggregation functions like `max()` apply to each group

```
select id, max(value)
from your_table
group by id
```